# CastleDynamic proxy: NullReferenceException when calling method of a proxy

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm using *StructureMap* to have an instance of an interface and I wrap it into a proxy with *Castle DynamicProxy*:

```
var proxy = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget<T>(
    ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>()
    , new SwitchInterceptor(isGranted, foundUser));
```

In the interceptor of type `IInterceptor`, I've got this code:

```
public override void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    if (this.CanExecute)
    {
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

When CanExecute is `true`, it always work but **sometimes** when CanExecute is `false`, I've got a weird `NullReferenceException` with a realy small stacktrace:

```
at Castle.Proxies.IGrantedReadProxy.ExecuteSomething()
```

I'm really lost and I don't know where to look. Do you have any idea about what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is when the return type is a non-nullable value type (e.g. `int`). In that case, the default return value of `null` that `invocation` has is not applicable. And you don't set it by calling `invocation.Proceed()` either, so you have to set it another way.

You have to explicitly set `invocation.ReturnValue` in those cases. Another option is to throw a more informative exception.

Comment: That's exactly the problem: in the case `CanExecute` is `false`, I set `invoker.ReturnValue`to the default value of the return type. And it works. Thank you very much!